# How can I pass gnome proxy settings via .desktop file?

Tags: gnome, proxy, desktop-environments, eclipse, .desktop

When I start Eclipse manually from org.gnome.Terminal, it can access the system proxy settings (neither in .profile nor in .bashrc, but in exported environment variables). When I start Eclipse via my homemade .desktop file, I need to enter the configuration in Eclipse manually; it looks as if the environment variables are not set.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Icon=/home/vk/eclipse/icon.xpm
Path=/home/vk/eclipse
Exec=/home/vk/eclipse/eclipse
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
```

I found nothing in org.gnome.Terminal.desktop that I looked like a switch to me that allowed passing of proxy settings / environment.

For now, I just open an extra tab in org.gnome.Terminal.desktop to start eclipse but that is just a workaround (I have to work from multiple sites with different proxy settings and want to use system settings in as many apps as possible).

I am running Debian strech up to date:

```
Linux excalibur 4.9.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2 (2018-01-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am grateful for any pointers.

Comment: I just ran into this same issue!  Seems really weird and hard to find any information about.  

I came across this gist, but it is really just a bandaid:
https://gist.github.com/JPvRiel/4e3f6f055b4ac9c31a302450bfdf0758

I want a fix that make it work when I click the .desktop file.

Comment: It would be nice if Gnome would handle this and it seems weird that it doesn't but the above gist works nicely.